# How to properly scale imported 3D model in Unity VR?

Tags: unity-game-engine, steamvr

I am currently trying to make a Unity scene where the scene basically is a 3D plan of a room. So I just imported the 3D model in my scene and added the SteamVR camera rig and it's working (in debug mode and once build). The only problem I have is that I can't seem to properly adjust the ratio between the scale of the player and the scale of the room. Does anyone know how to make proportion reals ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Most VR uses a `1 unit = 1 metre` scale (relative to the viewer).  Effectively, don't ever scale the user, only scale the room to suit the user (if you want the user to think they're small, just make the room bigger instead).

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming your object is created with respect to the room geometry. Then you can get a real tape measure and measure some distance in your actual room.

Then import this [asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/distance-tool-307) for measuring distances in Unity on your model. Measure the same distance in Unity on your model using this asset. Then scale your object based on the ratio between real tape measure and unity measure like this: `scale = real tape measure / unity measure`

As i said if your model is created wrt to room geometry you will get correct scale. Good luck!